# How do you position a text box in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Could you help me with positioning my textbox named "stuff" (If you have any good tutorials could you post those, too?).

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
month = now.month
day = now.day
year = now.year

stuff = "the month is %s the day is %d and they year is %s" % (month, day, 
year)

topwindow = tkinter.Tk()
textbox = tkinter.Text(topwindow)
textbox.configure(font=("Times New Roman", 50, "bold"))
textbox.insert( tkinter.INSERT, str(stuff))
textbox.pack()
topwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you want your textbox positioned?

Comment: The center, but I would like to know how to position it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to position widgets in tkinter. Tkinter has three *geometry managers*: `pack`, `place`, and `grid` which are used for placement.

`pack` operates on the concept of a box. you "pack" items to one of the sides of an empty box. It is best for when you need to place a single widget, or a group of widgets in a single row or a single column.

`grid` does as its name implies, it organizes widgets in a grid. Every widget is given a row and a column, and there are additional options for spanning rows and column, padding, etc.

`place` is the least used geometry manager. Its main advantage is it allows you to do absolute positioning. It also allows relative positioning (eg: you can place one widget in the exact middle of another). The downsize to using `place` is that you have to do a lot of the math yourself, and it's much harder to get widgets to behave properly when fonts or resolutions change, or the user changes the size of the window.

The advantage that `grid` and `pack` have over `place` is that they will automatically grow or shrink the window to fit its contents. This means that you don't much have to worry about the size of your GUI, it will become the size it needs to be. `pack` and `grid` are the best choice if you want your UI to be responsive -- to react properly when run on different systems with different resolutions or fonts, and for when the user resizes the window.

The [tkinter book at effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) is one place that has some good basic documentation:

- [The grid geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)
- [The pack geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)
- [The place geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

It's important to note that you can use all three within the same application -- they all have strengths and weaknesses. The only caveat is that you can't use both `grid` and `pack` on different widgets that share the same parent (or master, depending on the terminology you prefer).

Comment: As of writing this comment, effbot.org does not seem to be active, and the links are not that helpful. However, there is an archived version of the blog, see for example the article on the [the pack geometry manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111222645/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm). Maybe the links on the answer could be updated, with an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Just use 
    `textbox.pack()` it will be placed in the center if you want it to be positioned in the left use `textbox.pack(side=LEFT)` or if to be positioned in right use `textbox.pack(side=RIGHT)`

Comment: `pack`, all by itself, will not place a widget in the center of it's parent or master. You need to supply additional options. The default behavior of `pack()` is to place the widget at the top of the available space.